# split sentences and combine words in Apache Beam

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a PCollection of dictionaries:

```
{'sentence': 'foo bar', 'value' : 5 }
{'sentence': 'one bar', 'value' : 2 }
```

I would like to space split the sentences, give the same value for each word of the sentence, and then aggregate by word with sum function. My desired output is:

```
{'word': 'foo', 'value' : 5}
{'word': 'bar', 'value' : 7}
{'word': 'one', 'value' : 2}
```

I defined a function that splits the sentence and returns a list of dicts for each sentence:

```
def word_dicts(row):
 words = row['sentence'].split(' ')
 return [{'word' : word, 'value' : row['value'] } for word in words]
```

I put this function in a `beam.Map`, then i'm using `beam.CombineGlobally(beam.combiners.ToListCombineFn())` to get a list of all lists of dictoinaries

```
[[{'word': 'foo', 'value' : 5},{'word': 'bar', 'value' : 5}],[{'word': 'foo', 'value' : 5},{'word': 'one', 'value' : 2}]]
```

And then i'm stuck because i can't see how to Partition this list and do the Combine to get the final results.

Do you know a simplest way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`beam.Map` is useful with one-to-one transformation, but here you need `beam.FlatMap` that does one-to-many transformation.

`word_dicts` needs to return a list of tuples (see below) and `beam.Map(word_dicts)` can be replaced by `beam.FlatMap(word_dicts)`.

```
def word_dicts(row):
  words = row['sentence'].split(' ')
  return [(word, row['value']) for word in words]
```

The rest should be very similar to [`wordcount`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py) example.
You can apply `beam.GroupByKey` and `beam.Map(lambda kv : (kv[0], sum(kv[1])))`. You can also do `beam.CombineValues(lambda x,y : x + y)`.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think about using key/value pairs...